# Replacing xfce with awesome in Xubuntu

Tags: xfce, awesome

I'm using Xubuntu 13.04 with xfce 4.10. I'm trying to entirely replace xfce 4.10 (not uninstall, but replace) with awesome. So far, I have yet to even get awesome to run.

The steps that I have tried thus far:

1. Install awesome with `sudo apt-get install awesome`
2. ~/.xinitrc now just contains `exec awesome`.
3. `mkdir ~/.config/awesome/` and `cp /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua ~/.config/awesome/`

I've tried restarting, I've tried just running awesome (I get `E: awesome: main:445: another window manager is already running`, which is expected, but I'd really like to start up my session in awesome, not have to manually quit xfce and then start awesome).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you unable to simply select the session type from your display manager?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not correct way to do it, but I just did:

```
cd /usr/bin ; mv xfwm4 xfwm4! ; ln -s awesome xfwm4
```

And restarted X.

Comment: That's actually kind of hilarious. Thanks for the response. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the install. Pretty easy fix. Answer here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1094811

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.